# What is the correct way to define MQL4 "#import of static class methods"?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

What I'm trying to achieve is define classes (using **`MQL4`**) in separate files and use the methods from those classes in the main code. Essentially importing static class member functions.

```
 class example{                                            // ____ in example.mq4
   public:
   static void myfunction(void) export { .. do something .. }
 }
```

---

```
 class example{                                            // ____ in example.mqh
   public:
   static void myfunction(void);
 }
```

---

```
 #include <example.mqh>                                    // ____ in main.mq4:
 #import "example.ex4"
     void example::myfunction(void);
 #import
```

Results in a compile error when using the function as follows:

```
void OnInit(){
   example::myfunction();
}
```

compiler error:

> **`myfunction:  function must have a body`**

(note `example.mq4` is compiled to `example.ex4` and can be imported ok)

Answer (score 0):

### "new"-MQL4 syntax is evolving

for the indicated purpose,

the class definition syntax shall be enough, upon instantiation of a class, its **`public`** methods are possible to be invoked on instance-objects.

### Compile-time syntax:

Exporting a function without it's **`class`**-inheritance ( taking together the whole `class` *container* ) does not fit the OOP concept. This is clearly visible in the `OnInit()` call, where your code attempts to call a *function*, which is in fact a class-based **object-`method`** at a moment, where there has not yet been instantiated any **`object`**, on which the `method` ought to be performed `anObjectINSTANCE.aClassOrInstanceMETHOD()`.

So, just `#include`

```
class example{                                            // ____ in example.mqh

   public:
   static void myfunction() { .. do something; }

  }
```

---

```
// ----------------------------                          // ____ in main.mq4
#property strict            // "new"-MQL4

#include <example.mqh>      // include

example anObject;           // create a globally visible instance

// ----------------------------
void OnInit(){
     anObject.myfunction(); // request <anObject> to perform <myfunction> method on self

     return( EMPTY );       // "new"-MQL4 insists on return even on void fun()
  }
```

Comment: * Having larger projects where all source code files are to be included into a main file, sort of defeats the purpose of OOP where we want to make public methods available and hide private and protected methods. 
* And its impractical from debugging and error preventing point of view to incude all sources into a main. So only class definitions need to be available to resolve links to objects, as is the case with the DLL's. 
* Perhaps there is a better solution ?

Comment: Oh yes, there is. Either a use a proxy class whose methods mediate interaction with non-public implementation, or go into a fully distributed-processing model, where the private implementation is completely external to the MQL4 code-base and provide just interacting agents ( we use ZeroMQ signalling / messaging layer for distributed processing for several years already and love the agent-based model - both for system services offloading, GPU-grid computing, AI/ML-predictive facilities co-integrated AlgoTrading / MMI-GUI-augmented Trading et al )